# Bare bones angular js throws error - [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

I have a super simple angular js app with the latest version. I have no idea why it's throwing this error. The entire code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <p>{{1+2}}</p>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the error is:

```
todo.js:1 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%2…tension%3A%2F%2Fkdhniogamakmhndnlahkfcnlihmpfdjb%2Fjs%2Ftodo.js%3A1%3A7033)
```

Things that I tried and didn't work:

- Added `<script>` for angular router js
- Put the ng-app on `<html>` instead of `<body>`
- Included a dummy controller which does nothing
- Visited the link in the error, doesn't explain what the issue is

Nothing seems to work and I've spent over 2 hours so far. Any help will be appreciated :(.

Edit: The code itself works i.e. the `<p>` tag displays 3. But the error doesn't make sense to me. What is `todo.js`?

Comment: Please provide your `todo.js` script.

Comment: @MickaëlB - There is no `todo.js` script! I don't know where it's coming from! My entire project is the lines you see above.

Comment: Given code working fine, I am not getting any error in console (FireFox and Chrome).

Comment: @Paarth - weird, maybe there's something wrong with my server? I'll try on another machine.

Comment: @PlastyGrove What server do you use ?

Comment: @MickaëlB - my local machine, with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`